# Post user geolocation to Django class based view

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am trying to post user geolocation to Django class based view. Apparently, javascript is not so friendly to me. How can I post user geolocation to `UserProfileView` class based view in django, ajax?

```
<body>

<div>
   <div>
    <strong>Current Position: </strong> {{ profile.user_location }}<br/>
    </div>

<label for="locations-status">Enable Location?</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="locations-status">
<form id="location_form" method="POST" action="{% url 'rent_app:add-location' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
 <button type="button" id="send-my-url-to-django-button">Send URL to Django View</button>
</form>
{% block js %}
<script>
      function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
      }

      $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
          }
        }
      });

      if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          function (position) {
            console.log('Position has been set successfully');
            console.log(position.coords);
          
         dataToSend = {
              "permission": $("input[name=locations-status]").is(':checked'),
              "user_location": position,
            };
          });
      }
        
          
$("#send-my-url-to-django-button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: 'json',
              url: "{% url 'rent_app:add-location' %}",
              data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
              success: function (msg) {
                console.log('Succeeded!');            
              },
              error: function (err) {
                console.log('Error!');
              }
            });
          }, function (error) {
              console.log('Position could not be obtained.');
          }
        );
</script>
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

views.py:

```
class UserProfileView(View):
    form_class = UserProfileModelForm
    template_name = "user_profile.html"

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        user_locations = UserProfile.objects.user_location()
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, 
            {"form": form, "user_location": user_locations})

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.is_ajax and self.request.method == "POST":
            form = self.form_class(self.request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                instance = form.save()
                ser_instance = serializers.serialize('json', [ instance, ])
                # send to client side.
                return JsonResponse({"instance": ser_instance}, status=200)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error": form.errors}, status=400)

        return JsonResponse({"error": ""}, status=400)
```

Answer (score 0):

The context is `{"form": form, "user_location": user_locations})` you don't have any `profile` passed in the context. I think you need to use `{{ user_location }}` instead of `{{ profile.user_location }}`

Comment: I corrected to `{{user_location}}` on the html, but the main issue appears to be in submitting the form; i.e. JavaScript which says `position could not be obtained`. I am not very familiar with JavaScript, but i suspect something wrong in that part of the ajax code.

Comment: Is the form valid? One thing that you can try is to check the network tab in chrome/mozilla or whatever you are using and check the request to the form. And additionally you can try to print the error argument that you are giving in the AJAX request where you output the `position could not be obtained`. Also check if you have allowed your location being sent to the browser.

Comment: It prints position could not be obtained in the console. Just doesn't capture the position, i guess?

Comment: I think your navigator works but I just saw that you have 2 callbacks in the click's function. Delete the one with `error`(starting with this `}, function (error) {`) 

You are using the ajax request as a eventData and the second callback as a handler. So try to delete the second one its useless anyway. You are catching your errors with AJAX.

Comment: I am sorry, there is still POST error. It seems the DataToSend dictionary. The modelform has `id` and `user_location` fields. What I can't figure out is to put the `position.coords` to DataToSend, apparently throws error.

Comment: I wanted Apartments within 2km distance query, may be I don't even need to store user location.

Comment: Try to set a new variable on top of everything which would be the data to send then simply update that variable. I think the scope that you are executing might refer to different object or non-existent one and that would cause an error. Try to print `dataToSend` before you ajax request just to be sure that there is the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the javascript work. Thank you, that would be helpful.